# Remove value in Input field on refreshing Edge

Tags: html, angular, forms, microsoft-edge

I made some input fields. Every input field has a formControlName and in the constructor of my component I'll set the FormGroup so I can validate my inputs. My Problem is, that if I refresh my browser on Edge the value of the fields are not cleared and if I'm validating the fields with their formGroup the'll be invalid even if there are valid values in it. It is suspicious that Edge only keeps the value of text input fields. The password input fields are cleared properly.

Has anyone an idea how to fix my problem?

I've already tried different stuff like setting an `[(ngModel)]` on every input field, setting `autocomplete=off` and other stuff. I'm really thankfull for every help.

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label>Nr*</label>
   <input type="text" formControlName="nr" required>
</p>
<p>
  <label>MNr*</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="mNr" required>
</p>
<p>
  <label>PIN*</label>
  <input type="password" formControlName="pin" required>
</p>
```

Component.ts

```
export class QueryComponent {
  queryForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.queryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        nr: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d*$')]],
        mNr: ['', [Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^(0041|041|\\+41|\\+\\+41|41)?(0|\\(0\\))?([7] 
            [3-9]{1})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$')]],
        pin: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\\d{8}$')]]
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code, you could set the default value for the input text control.

Code in the html page:

```
 <form [formGroup]="heroForm" #formDir="ngForm">

    <div [hidden]="formDir.submitted">

      <div class="cross-validation" [class.cross-validation-error]="heroForm.errors?.identityRevealed && (heroForm.touched || heroForm.dirty)">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input id="name" class="form-control"
                formControlName="name" required >

          <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
              class="alert alert-danger">

            <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
              Name is required.
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
              Name must be at least 4 characters long.
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
              Name cannot be Bob.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
          <input id="alterEgo" class="form-control"
              formControlName="alterEgo"  >

          <div *ngIf="alterEgo.pending">Validating...</div>
          <div *ngIf="alterEgo.invalid" class="alert alert-danger alter-ego-errors">
            <div *ngIf="alterEgo.errors?.uniqueAlterEgo">
              Alter ego is already taken.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="heroForm.errors?.identityRevealed && (heroForm.touched || heroForm.dirty)" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
            Name cannot match alter ego.
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
        <select id="power" class="form-control"
            formControlName="power" required >
          <option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
        </select>

        <div *ngIf="power.invalid && power.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="power.errors.required">Power is required.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
             [disabled]="heroForm.invalid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
             (click)="formDir.resetForm({})">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="submitted-message" *ngIf="formDir.submitted">
    <p>You've submitted your hero, {{ heroForm.value.name }}!</p>
    <button (click)="formDir.resetForm({})">Add new hero</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

code in the component.ts:

```
export class HeroFormReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible', 'Weather Changer'];

  hero = { name: 'Dr.', alterEgo: 'Dr. What', power: this.powers[0] };

  heroForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4),
        forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
      ]),
      'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo, {
        asyncValidators: [this.alterEgoValidator.validate.bind(this.alterEgoValidator)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),
      'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
    },  { validators: identityRevealedValidator }); // <-- add custom validator at the FormGroup level
  }

  get name() { return this.heroForm.get('name'); }

  get power() { return this.heroForm.get('power'); }

  get alterEgo() { return this.heroForm.get('alterEgo'); }

  constructor(private alterEgoValidator: UniqueAlterEgoValidator) { }
}
```

More details code, you could check [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdvmggjlbkp?file=src%2Findex.html). And, you could also refer to [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-component-class) to add form validation.

Besides, I think you could also try to use JavaScript functions to clear the value, in the page onload event, you could get the related input elements and clear the value.